# How to display two images in each Qlabel PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

Hi I'm beginner in PyQt5 and my little project is creating image predictor GUI with PyQt5 Designer to detect if an image is a cat or not by clicking on PREDICT button. I can browse which file I want to predict by Browse file button. The problem is whenever I select a cat image added by browse file button, and click on PREDICT button, image associated with the PREDICT button doesn't appear.

[image]

Documentation about Qlabel doesn't provide me enough clear information to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(1600, 900)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

    self.photo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.photo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 761, 651))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(40)
    self.photo.setFont(font)
    self.photo.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
    self.photo.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
    self.photo.setLineWidth(5)
    self.photo.setMidLineWidth(0)
    self.photo.setScaledContents(True)
    self.photo.setObjectName("photo")

    self.browseFile = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.browseFile.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 700, 151, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.browseFile.setFont(font)
    self.browseFile.setObjectName("browseFile")
    self.browseFile.clicked.connect(self.browse_file)

    self.predict = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.predict.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 750, 231, 61))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(17)
    font.setBold(False)
    font.setWeight(50)
    self.predict.setFont(font)
    self.predict.setObjectName("predict")
    self.predict.clicked.connect(self.show_predict)

    self.photo2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.photo2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 20, 791, 651))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(40)
    self.photo2.setFont(font)
    self.photo2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
    self.photo2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
    self.photo2.setLineWidth(5)
    self.photo2.setScaledContents(True)
    self.photo2.setObjectName("photo2")

    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 700, 521, 31))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1600, 25))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.photo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "INPUT"))
    self.browseFile.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse file"))
    self.predict.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PREDICT"))
    self.photo2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OUTPUT"))

def browse_file(self):
    directory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Browse File", "", "PNG (*.PNG *.png")[0]
    print(directory)
    pixmap =  QtGui.QPixmap(directory)
    self.photo.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(self.photo.size()))
    self.lineEdit.setText('{}'.format(directory))

def _set_text(self, text):
    return text

def show_predict(self):
    self.photo2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.realpath("image/predictions.png")))  

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I must admit that I never heart about `QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName()`. However, guessing what it does, please, be aware of `self.predict.setObjectName("predict")` vs. `def show_predict(self):`. Maybe, you could have found it by yourself if you had added a (temporary) debug console output to your signal slot - to see whether it is called at all.

Comment: @Scheff thank you for your reply. Actually `def show_predict(self):` is my function to locate and display my prediction image the other one is just giving object a name. It's working fine if I only use one Qlabel to show my images but it doesn't if I put two Qlabel at MainWindow.

Comment: Welcome sswwann, have you debugged the code to find where it stops working?

Comment: I just found out that you connected your signal handler explicitly with `self.predict.clicked.connect(self.show_predict)`. (So, my doubts about `QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName()` were regardless.) You may check whether the `self.photo2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.realpath("image/predictions.png")))` might fail. Are you sure that `image/predictions.png` can be resolved properly? Maybe, try an absolute path for debugging.

Comment: @Scheff yes I'm already using signal handler to function `show_predict` .  Turns out it's a path problem, my bad. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my mistake, solved by using absolute path instead of in-directory path.