# PyQt5 setstylesheet eror

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

this is my source
but when I click a button and after it another button the color wont change and it will stay the last color

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(702, 557)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 80, 101, 81))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.red)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 80, 101, 81))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.blue)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 80, 101, 81))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.yellow)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 220, 101, 81))
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.green)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 220, 101, 81))
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.black)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 220, 101, 81))
        self.pushButton_6.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.white)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 360, 101, 81))
        self.pushButton_7.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.purple)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 360, 101, 81))
        self.pushButton_8.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.orange)
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 360, 101, 81))
        self.pushButton_9.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pink)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "red"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "blue"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "yellow"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "green"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "black"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "white"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "purple"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "orange"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("Dialog", "pink"))
    def red(self):
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
    def blue(self):
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;")
    def yellow(self):
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
    def green(self):
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
    def black(self):
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
    def white(self):
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
    def purple(self):
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: purple")
    def orange(self):
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;")
    def pink(self):
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink;")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

when  click another buttons it wont change the color

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The MCVE of the OP appeared overly complicated to me. Hence, I started to investigate into this with my own attempt first:

`testStyleSheet.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QPushButton

print("Qt Version: {}".format(QT_VERSION_STR))
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
qDlg = QDialog()
qGrid = QGridLayout()
configs = [ \
  [ "red", 0, 0 ], [ "green", 0, 1 ], [ "blue", 0, 2 ], \
  [ "cyan", 1, 0 ], [ "yellow", 1, 1 ], [ "magenta", 1, 2], \
  [ "pink", 2, 0 ], [ "brown", 2, 1 ], [ "gray", 2, 2 ] \
]
for config in configs:
  color = config[0]
  qBtn = QPushButton(color)
  qGrid.addWidget(qBtn, config[1], config[2]) 
  def makeLambda(color):
    return lambda state: \
      qDlg.setStyleSheet("background-color: {};".format(color))
  qBtn.clicked.connect(makeLambda(color))
qDlg.setLayout(qGrid)
qDlg.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.11.3
```

[image: GIF animation with demo session]

OK, it's working in general.

---

Having a closer look onto OPs code, I eventually found why it doesn't work as expected:

OP connected all signal slots to `self.push_button`:

```
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.red)
...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.blue)
...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.yellow)
...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.green)
...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.black)
...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.white)
...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.purple)
...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.orange)
...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pink)
```

This actually looks like a simple typo but it might be overlooked as quite good hidden in the code wall. (I must admit I didn't see this until looking very close onto the code.)

So, if `self.push_button` is clicked then all nine slots are called for this button, the `pink` is the last of them. (Hence, the effect of the others just doesn't become visible.)

If any other button is clicked just nothing is called.

Having fixed this, OPs sample is working as well.

---

<s>It seems that OP intended to fix this by connecting the slots by name:</s>
There is also the auto-connect in OPs code (probably inserted by the code generator of Qt-s GUI builder):

```
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
```

I'm quite sure that this part doesn't work as well. I remembered that I once investigated into how the auto-connect works. (Not that I ever plan to use it. It appears much too fragile to me where I prefer maintenance-friendly solutions (but this is just my personal opinion). However, I once investigated into this out of curiosity…)

[**pyqt auto connect signal**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63341106/7478597)

Recalling that, I came to the conclusion that none of the working schemes are matched by OPs code.

Comment: 1. The code provided by the OP is not "overly complicated", it's standard code automatically generated by the pyuic tool, starting from ui files generated in Designer. 2. Those files should never be edited, but only imported and used to create the UI on Qt widget instances or as bases for multiple inheritance, so what should be pointed out is not the complicated example, but the modifications applied to it. 3. `connectSlotsByName`, along with `retranslateUi`, are also added by pyuic for convenience, so that a widget "configured" on that form can be automatically connected to compatible slots.

Comment: @musicamante I must admit that I myself never used the GUI builder but was suspecting that it was involved. I considered to fix OPs sample concerning auto-connection but finally gave up. I was uncertain how the `connectSlotsByName()` can pick-up the slots from a non-`QObject` like OPs `class Ui_Dialog` (if it can at all).

Comment: @ScheffsCat the problem is that `connectSlotsByName` only works on the *target* instance (`Dialog`, here), which should be a QObject based class, and already have those slots implemented, like `on_pushButton_clicked` or `on_pushButton_2_clicked`. In the case of the OP it wouldn't have worked (the target has no such methods, since it's a basic QDialog) unless creating a subclass of QDialog that would have those slots and would create an instance of `Ui_Dialog` and call it against itself: `self.ui = Ui_Dialog()` `self.ui.setupUi(self)`.

Comment: @musicamante Yeah, I came to a similar conclusion. I got the feeling that I had OPs code to change significantly. If I would rewrite this on my own... -- actually, this is what I already did initially. :-)

Comment: @ScheffsCat well, that's *one* way of doing things. With complex UIs, having a tool like Designer is incredibly useful, as it furtherly "expands" the MV[C] pattern and provides ways to create abstract interfaces that are much more useful to keep the code well organized. While I deeply understand that low-level creation of user interfaces provides lots of benefits, it also requires lots of mental efforts that often leads to *unnecessary* efforts (aka: no performance benefit): whenever you've a non-dynamic UI, at a certain point there's no benefit in doing all of that by code. The abstractions->

Comment: -> that a UI tool like Designer provides allows the programmer to better focus on the logical aspects of the program, no matter how the UI is organized. This is a very important aspect that should *never* be underestimated. There are conditions that logically require a basic code implementation for better optimization, but using a separate tool that actually "sets up" the UI is of a great help whenever complex user interfaces (and UX experience) are involved.

Comment: @musicamante Please, note that I never would dare to write that _The code provided by the OP is "overly complicated"_. I wrote _The MCVE of the OP appeared overly complicated to me._ That's a difference and it was carefully worded... Whether a GUI builder is a help or a burden may be subject of personal reception. IMHO, GUI builders have their strengths for entry level programmers (just pick from a graphical menu instead of scrolling through long text docs) and their weaknesses (as soon as the UI contains a lot of repetition). But I must admit that I've very few experience with GUI builders...

Comment: @SheffsCat I agree that your phrasing is not absolute (but, being the OP a "beginner" either on SO or in PyQt, that wouldn't change that much on their eyes). Automatic systems like pyuic are known to create lots of what some would call "garbage code", but that's just expected: even the .ui files have lots of tags that are often unnecessary, but those *have* to exist for simplicity and compliancy. Just as with any automated tool, you've to balance results and effectiveness: as soon as you master the underlying language/toolkit, you'll be able to decide if the automation is a benefit or not.

Comment: BUT. I also believe that here on SO, while we should usually focus on specific answers to specific questions, we should also try to find good balance in education and effectiveness of answers and point out the importance of aspects dealed in the answer we provide, within their context. Take for instance your answer: the actual and real problem was the wrong signal connection, but the whole answer seemed to point otherwise (code presentation, uneffective implementation). I understand that your experience doesn't involve Designer/uic, but that aspect doesn't really relate with the result.